# Please help to detect ETHEREUM JSON key file

Tags: private-key, public-key, keystore

Time: 2014 year.

I have next key:
{"public_key":"02f6197ef15d989898b11c6c0axxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "data":"8aba0051ff23fe95a13d2747a19261690ed80b4d5cf54xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","salt": "9a7995ca9a714b80b6xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","iv": "f06e8fe76f3xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"}

I have public address, i remember password, but i do not remember which software use this key.   I copied this and save into evernote. Help please, may be this json familiar to you?

Also may be found some solution on python to decode and extracy my private key?

Comment: I'm not sure, but this may be an old Ethereum keystore file? You can give it a try on MyCrypto's desktop app (https://download.mycrypto.com), or if that fails try the legacy version of MyCrypto (https://legacy.mycrypto.com/).

Comment: Could also be a custom format, but it looks like it uses AES-128/256 encryption so you can also possibly use a script to decrypt it.

Comment: yeah, this is exactly a JSON keystore file. There are a few versions of it, probably it is version 1

Comment: install `geth` and put this file into `keystore` directory, then at the console try to unlock the account